# Update Column from Separate Table When Not Match By Source

Tags: sql-server, merge, triggers

I am using SQL Management Studio 2012. 
I would like to update a field from a table that is not within the Target/Source relationship in a Store Procedure using a TRIGGER to update records from a View ([dbo].ActivityView tv) to an editable table ([dbo].ActivityTracker t).  Records fall in and out of the View based on a [COMPLETION] date field. If the [COMPLETION] date value is past the end of the Quarter, it drops out of the View but triggers a "Won't Be Complete" in the Target's [COMPLETION] column.  However, when this happens, I can't see when that update timestamp to the [COMPLETION] field took place since it is no longer within the View. The value exists in "THISOTHERTABLE" the View is based off. 
Therefore, I would like to update the field in the Target from "THISOTHERTABLE" if possible.

```
MERGE [dbo].[ActivityTracker] t --TARGET
USING  [dbo].[ActivityView] tv  --SOURCE
on tv.ID = t.ID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET t.ID = tv.ID,
Do Stuff...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
Do Stuff...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
Set t.TIMESTAMP = (select distinct o.TIMESTAMP from [dbp].THISOTHERTABLE o where t.ID = o.ID) END
```

"THISOTHERTABLE" has multiple records for the ID field, so I would have to select distinct TIMESTAMP to get only a single value for the unique ID in the TARGET table. However, THISOTHERTABLE already has only the MAX(TIMESTAMP) for TIMESTAMP so no need to do the MAX. The TARGET table has only one unique record for each ID.  Is it possible to write an UPDATE subquery like I have shown in the last line of example code?

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Looks like your query should work, if you put a UPDATE between the last THEN and Set. Have you tried it?

Comment: If what you say is true about the MAX timestamp thing is true then you would  want to SELECT TOP(1) instead of SELECT DISTINCT, just to be careful.